# How can I calculate $(\frac{1}{n})!$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, factorial, gamma-function

Perhaps it is a stupid question, but I would like to know how to calculate 
$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)!$
I know $n! = n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots1$ and...?

> $$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)!$$

Comment: you seem to know the gamma function, so where is the problem?

Comment: $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!=\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: that's the problem. I do not know the gamma function..
How can I calculate $\Gamma(\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: The improper integral form is how you calculate the gamma function -
$$(\frac{1}{n})! = \Gamma(\frac{1}{n}+1) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Dario, you cannot. No closed form.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments

Comment: This answer is not so easy to understand if I do not know the theory of gamma function...
Maybe I should deepen this topic.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there isn't any nice closed form for $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)!$, apart from $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)! = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$ and the trivial $1!=1$.
However, if $n\in\{3,4,6,12,24\}$ we have that $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)!$ has a closed form in terms of elliptic integrals of the first kind, hence it can be computed really fast through the [AGM mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean). By recalling that $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)!=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$, have a look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments).